# ACCESS VBA Handling Numeric Values in Where Condition

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a fairly simply procedure that looks up data from a table and loads it in a pop-up form based on a selection from a listbox. The unique record identifier in the listbox is an integer (actually just the access auto-number field). I'm having trouble getting my select query to handle the value as a numeral (versus with quotes). When I remove the quotes from the criteria in the Where statement, the SQL no longer recognizes it but I'm not sure how to code the criteria so it remains a numeral. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Dim DB As Database
Dim Memo3a As Recordset

Dim txt_Subject As String
Dim txt_Category As String
Dim txt_Date As String
Dim txt_Memo As String
Dim txt_User As String
Dim txt_RecID As String
Dim ViewMemo As Form

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set Memo3a = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT [16_COMMENTS].[16_Subject], [16_COMMENTS].[16_Category], [16_COMMENTS].[16_CommentDate], [16_COMMENTS].[16_Comment], [16_COMMENTS].[16_User], [16_COMMENTS].[16_RecordID]  " & _
"FROM 16_COMMENTS  " & _
"WHERE ((([16_COMMENTS].[16_RecordID])='" & Me.lst_Memo3a & "'));")

DoCmd.OpenForm ("ViewMemo")
Set ViewMemo1 = Forms("ViewMemo")

ViewMemo1![txt_Subject].Value = Memo3a.Fields(0).Value
ViewMemo1![txt_Category].Value = Memo3a.Fields(1).Value
ViewMemo1![txt_Date].Value = Memo3a.Fields(2).Value
ViewMemo1![txt_Memo].Value = Memo3a.Fields(3).Value
ViewMemo1![txt_User].Value = Memo3a.Fields(4).Value
ViewMemo1![txt_RecID].Value = Memo3a.Fields(5).Value


Set DB = Nothing
Set Memo3a = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I think, should use ``"WHERE ((([16_COMMENTS].[16_RecordID])=" & Me.lst_Memo3a.Value & "));")`` - without ``'``

Comment: Apostrophe delimiters are for Text type field criteria. Date/Time uses #.